# How to position an object near a point on a screen regardless of size

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a Pong-like game based off of some older code I found on the internet. It manually set the screen dimensions originally, and did not take into account any other sized screens. I'm wanting to update it to put the bars say 10% from the edge of the screen, regardless of the size. I've tried various things and none have worked without some errors. The best I've been able to come up with is this.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "deprecation" })
private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) {
final Point point = new Point();
try {
    display.getSize(point);
} catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
    point.x = display.getWidth();
    point.y = display.getHeight();
}
return point;
}
```

This first bit should work on older and newer api correct? How do I use the information of the width and height to apply to the _screenHeight and _screenWidth used later? Yes I do realize that _screenWidth/2 won't get me the 10% from edge I'm looking for, one step at a time please.

```
//The ball
final int _ballSize = 10;
//Original 
//int _ballX = 100;     int _ballY = 100;
int _ballX = 500;   int _ballY = 500;
int _ballVelocityX = 3;     int _ballVelocityY = 3;

//The bats
final int _batLength = 75;  final int _batHeight = 10;
int _topBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);
final int _topBatY = 20;
int _bottomBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);  
//Original code
//final int _bottomBatY = 400;
final int _bottomBatY = 750;
final int _batSpeed = 3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the width & height of your screen, use the following code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();       
DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
_screenWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
_screenHeight  = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
```

Also, any "pixel" type parameter you hold should be divided by screen density in order to get device independent  pixels.

This code has proved to work on all devices running Android 2.2 and above.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: When I put your code in I, the getWindowManager, getResources both are undefined types, and the outMetrics gives me a syntax error VariableDeclaratorID expected. What else am I missing? btw I'm learning as I go. :D

Comment: are you calling this from your activity? If not, you should supply a WindowManager / Resources objects to whatever method is performing this calculation. getWindowManager & getResources are methods inside of Activity.

Comment: No, I'm not calling it from my activity. How do I go about supplying these to the method?

Comment: i've noticed your method is static? is there any reason for that? make it non-static, and make sure it's in the activity